# Android change images and text in list view by position with switch

Tags: android, android-listview, switch-statement, baseadapter

I'm working  baseadapter. I successfully adaptered images and text in list view. I have 3 images and texts. Now I want to change images and text background in list view click by position
this is a my  base adapter code

```
public class SlideMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] menu_items_id;

private final int[] Imageid;
TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public SlideMenuAdapter(Context context, String[] names, int[] Imageid)
         {
    mContext = context;

    this.Imageid = Imageid;
    this.menu_items_id = names;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return Imageid.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;

    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_slidemenu_adaper, null);
    textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.photo);

    textView.setText(menu_items_id[position]);

    textView.setTypeface(MainmoviesActivity.dejavusans);





    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return grid;
}
```

}
This is a main java code

```
int[] menu_images = { R.drawable.menu_schedule, R.drawable.menu_about,
        R.drawable.menu_booking };

int[] menu_imagesover = { R.drawable.schedule_ove, R.drawable.about_over,
        R.drawable.booking_over };
private String[] menu_namesEng = { "schedule_ove", "about_over", "about_over" };






    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8f332a"));
                imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
                break;

            case 1:
                textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }


        }

    });
```

I can change image and text only list view's firs item and when I click second item also first items's images and text changed again. What am I doing wrong? If anyone knows solution please help me.

Comment: Use View Holder for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use view instead of parent eg:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
```

Because using the parent, findViewById will go through the viewtree and return the first match, which is always the first item in the list.

May I also suggest using RecyclerView? :)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html